# How to pass ASP.NET Core Request.Cookies to helper function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm fairly new to C# and MVC and I'm building a little program to learn how to interact with cookies. Since there will probably be a piece of validation code repeated multiple times in my program, I'm trying to extract it into a helper function. However, whenever I try to pass `Request.Cookie` from inside a view method, I get this error:

```
CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Helpers.IsLoggedIn(IRequestCookieCollection)'
```

My view class (with some unneeded methods and imports removed):

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Accounts.Helpers;

namespace Program.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            bool loggedIn = MiscHelpers.IsLoggedIn(Request.Cookies);
        }
    }
}
```

My helper class:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace Program.Helpers
{
    public class MiscHelpers
    {
        public bool IsLoggedIn(IRequestCookieCollection cookies)
        {
            // code
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make the `IsLoggedIn` method `static`.

Answer (score 1):

Make your `MiscHelpers` class and the `IsLoggedIn` method `static`

Even just the method will be fine already.

Comment: Oh, of course. I would have picked up this error, but the message confused me into thinking that it was an issue with the arguments.

Comment: For the future: if you see `An object reference is required` and everything else is correct, it's always something to do with something not being `static`! Happy coding!